# Insert data in SQL Server with user input using loops in python

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I want to insert data from user input and calculations into an SQL table. Here is the code I have so far:

```
active = list(c.execute("SELECT hrm_id, name, wage FROM employees WHERE active=1;"))

payroll_date = input("Add the date of the payroll: ")

for i in range(len(active)):

print(active[1])
days_worked = float(input("Type days worked: "))
wage = float(active[2])
hrm_id = int(active[0])
amount_owed = days_worked * wage

sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.payroll(hrm_id, days_worked, amt_owed, payroll_date) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)"
data = [hrm_id, days_worked, amount_owed, payroll_date]
c.execute(sql, data)
c.commit()
```

It is console based and I want to print the name, type the days and then calculate the salary, but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\gnsta\OneDrive\Payroll App\payrollcalc.py", line 14, in <module>
    wage = float(active[2])
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'pyodbc.Row'
```

I get that the data isn't float and strings but pyodbc.Row, but I can't find a way to change that.

Comment: You can't do `list(c.execute(...))`.  `cursor.execute` starts a query object.  You have to call `fetchall` on that cursor to get the actual rows.  So. `c.execute(...)` / `for row in c.fetchall():`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `fetchall()` and iterate over the rows directly rather than trying to use `len()`:

```
cursor = conn.execute("....")
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row[1]) // etc
```

Read [the docuementation](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Objects) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Logs Logs Logs tells you the exact problem. active[2] is returning entire row of data instead of wage value. Always focus on logs it tells you all how to fix it i.e. **TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'pyodbc.Row'**
It is returning row instead. Now you got it right! I will not write the code but I am sure you can fix it. Now focus on type error and you will get to the solution. hint,
for emp active:
wage = float(employee[2])
hrm_id = int(employee[0])

Now you got it!